# Merging a previously merged commit

Tags: git

I've pushed some changes directly to the 'dev' branch of a code base with SHA 'x'.  I've taken a branch from 'dev' (let's called this branch 'B') with 'x' as the HEAD.  I didn't want to check in 'x' into 'dev' so I created another check-in directly into 'dev' with SHA 'y', undoing all the changes from 'x' (the reason why I didn't just revert the changes is because I don't have the permissions to do a ForcePush).  Now, on 'B' I have 'x' as HEAD, as I previously said and I will be doing a lot of further check-ins to 'B'.

The question is, when I merge 'B' into 'dev' will I have problems because 'x' has already been merged into 'dev' previously and now I will be doing it again?

Comment: The correct way to handle this would be to do another revert, of your revert. If `x` is already on `dev`, you cannot merge `x` into `dev`.

Comment: Can you see if the following matches your situation? https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0dohjdplba39jm/SO52690626.pdf?dl=0 - Apologies for it being a pdf, GoodNotes export to image makes the whole thing black it seems, other than the highlights.